# How do I find the equivalence class when an ordered pair is given?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

> Let  be the relation on the set of ordered pairs of positive
> integers (i.e. ℤ+ × ℤ+) such that ((, ), (, )) ∈  is and only
> if  +  =  + . Show that  is an equivalence relation. Find
> the equivalence class of (1,2).

I did show that R is an equivalence relation. Next I tried to find the equivalence class like this:
Let [x] be the equivalence class of (1,2).
Therefore,

[x] = {(e, f) ∈ ℤ+ × ℤ+ | (e, f)R(1, 2)}

1 + f = 2 + e

From here onwards I don't understand what to do.

Comment: What do $p$ and $q$ have to do with $e$ and $f$?

Comment: @aschepler that was a mistake. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}[x]&=[(1,2)]\\&=\{(e,f)\in\Bbb Z^+\times\Bbb Z^+\mid(e,f)\mathrel{R}(1,2)\}&&\text{definition: equivalence class}\\&=\{(e,f)\in\Bbb Z^+\times\Bbb Z^+\mid e+2=f+1\}&&\text{definition: }R\\&=\{(e,f)\in\Bbb Z^+\times\Bbb Z^+\mid f=1+e\}\\&=\{(e,1+e)\mid e\in\Bbb Z^+\}\end{align}$

Please lemme know if that's clear enough.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a basic MathJax reference and tutorial. You did make one mistake, which I’ve corrected: $e$ ranges over $\Bbb Z^+$, not $\Bbb R$.